# How to pass correct context in a fragment with recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making an android app in Kotlin, that is supposed to represent my CV. I made it with fragments and recycler view in mind. The first tab in tabLayout is supposed to have my biography, second should have education and third work experience. Also, the second and third tab should be made with recycler view. Problem is that one of the recycler views return null where context is. Education and work experience work in the same way.

I've tried different context types and didn't find any that work. Also tried moving layoutManager and DefaultItemAnimator to MainActivity, but it didn't help ( I used "this" as context when I moved it to MainActivity).

```
Github link: https://github.com/CookieTheMonsta/MyCV
```

```
class Education: Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): Education {
            return Education()
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.education,container,false)
        educationDisplay.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(container?.context,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
        educationDisplay.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        educationDisplay.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(container?.context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL))
        return view
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setUpUi()
    }

    private fun setUpUi() {
        viewPager.adapter = FragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)


        displayData()

    }

    fun displayData() {

        /*educationDisplay.adapter = EducationAdapter(EducationRepository.educations)
        workexpDisplay.adapter = WorkExperienceAdapter(WorkRepository.works)*/
    }
}
```

Error list from Logcat

```
2019-04-10 15:57:44.260 9004-9004/hr.ferit.sumigaborna.mycv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: hr.ferit.sumigaborna.mycv, PID: 9004
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hr.ferit.sumigaborna.mycv/hr.ferit.sumigaborna.mycv.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: educationDisplay must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: educationDisplay must not be null
        at hr.ferit.sumigaborna.mycv.MainActivity.displayData(MainActivity.kt:39)
        at hr.ferit.sumigaborna.mycv.MainActivity.setUpUi(MainActivity.kt:33)
        at hr.ferit.sumigaborna.mycv.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

App should have 3 tabs, first is biography, which you can ignore because it doesn't give problems. Education and work experience tabs should give recycler views with my info in it. But they don't because

Comment: The context is not null, the RV "educationDisplay" is null

Comment: Why do you want to set adapter for `educationDisplay` in activity? It's a RV inside Fragment, so `Education` should keep all logic itself, not Activity

Comment: educationDisplay will be not null in Fragment's onViewCreated... (of course if you are using some kinds of auto binder)

Comment: It says that `educationDisplay must not be null` meaning it is `null`. Maybe it is not in the layout?

Comment: Your Activity should not be directly calling into the Views of a Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling your fragments UI in the Activity, which you should not and thats why you end up with a NPE.

Let's go step by step. Define the Activity and set the ViewPager along with its tab's behaviours, and that's the only UI logic your Activity class will have

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setUpUi()
    }

    private fun setUpUi() {
        viewPager.adapter = FragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        // set tabLayout's behaviour with the corresponding fragments
    }
}
```

Now that your ViewPager is set, and you have added the Fragment, handle your Fragments View, for example:

```
class Education: Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): Education {
            return Education()
        }
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        displayEducationData()
    }

    private fun displayEducationData() {
        educationDisplay.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
        educationDisplay.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
   educationDisplay.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(activity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL))
        educationDisplay.adapter = EducationAdapter(EducationRepository.educations)
    } 
}
```

Now do the same for the WorkExperience Fragment.

PS: I'm assuming you are using Kotlin view extension, if not dont forget to get the reference to educationDisplay with `findViewById` inside `displayEducationData()` before calling anything on it

Comment: I had to put the code from displayEducationData() to "override fun onViewCreated". After that, it worked as intended.